# this if statement drop me an unreachable error in python

Tags: python, bayesian

I don't know why this if statement drop me this error, at the beginning I thought maybe my python version had a problem, son I uninstall it and then I install it again, this is my code.

```py
def calc_bayes(prior_A, prob_B_dado_A, prob_B):
    return (prior_A * prob_B_dado_A) / prob_B
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        prob_cancer = 1 / 100000
        prob_sintoma_dado_cancer = 1
        prob_sintoma_dado_no_cancer = 10 / 99999
        prob_no_cancer = 1 - prob_cancer
        prob_sintoma = (prob_sintoma_dado_cancer * prob_cancer) + (prob_sintoma_dado_no_cancer * prob_cancer)
        prob_cancer_dado_sintoma = calc_bayes (prob_cancer, prob_sintoma_dado_cancer, prob_sintoma)
        print(prob_cancer_dado_sintoma)
```

Comment: you are in a function so you cant be in main...

Comment: you've that `if` statement after a `return`. No code directly after `return` gets executed. Perhaps you meant to have it outside the function? Please read the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and pay attention to why indentation is important in python.

Comment: no, we suggest you to read the tutorial.

Comment: thank for your help, I'm a junior developer yet. I'll read it.

Comment: Chase, you were right,  I had an identation problem, I could solved it. But I'll read the tutorial, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments, you cannot write _*name*_ = _*main*_ inside definitions. Instead, I think you want to do this

```
def calc_bayes(prior_A, prob_B_dado_A, prob_B):
    return (prior_A * prob_B_dado_A) / prob_B
if __name__ == '__main__':
        prob_cancer = 1 / 100000
        prob_sintoma_dado_cancer = 1
        prob_sintoma_dado_no_cancer = 10 / 99999
        prob_no_cancer = 1 - prob_cancer
        prob_sintoma = (prob_sintoma_dado_cancer * prob_cancer) + (prob_sintoma_dado_no_cancer * prob_cancer)
        prob_cancer_dado_sintoma = calc_bayes (prob_cancer, prob_sintoma_dado_cancer, prob_sintoma)
        print(prob_cancer_dado_sintoma)
```